# Error when my selenium script is launching Internet Explorer

Tags: maven, selenium, internet-explorer, junit

When my test script try to open Internet Explorer, I have an error.

Here is my test script :

```
package selenium;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class RegistrationTest{

public  int a = 1;

@Test //This is JUnit annotation

public void testRegister(){

        WebDriver driver ;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.navigate().to("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");
        driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

        driver.quit();

}           

 }
```

My POM.xml is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cgi.nouguierc</groupId>
<artifactId>WD-Automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>selenium.MainJar</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                     <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                     <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                     </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I launch RegistrationTest, Internet is opening, going to the adress "http://newtours.demoaut.com/" and then doing nothing.

And in the console I have some errors :

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.0.0.0
Listening on port 44920
Only local connections are allowed
mars 29, 2017 3:16:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake    createSession
INFOS: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Point is that I can't check or uncheck the box "Enable protected..." (see the screenshot below) because I am on a work network so I can't do what I want.

[Screenshot of the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPoGm.png)

Maybe someone can help me :)

Comment: Can try out once providing the full path of the IE driver as follows:

`String driverPath = "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\";`
`System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");`

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: It didn't solved my problem... Sorry

Comment: Is it the same problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. There is just the line : Listening on port 41586 which is different

Comment: I have checked your code, its perfectly executing fine in IE without the DesiredCapability. Issue must be with `(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true)` Checkout that.

Comment: Remove the DesiredCapabilities Class if not required. Things should be fine.

Comment: Yes it is working without it because you can check all the checkbox or uncheck all the checkbox (I show it on the screenshot). But I can't. I have some checkbox checked and some checkbox are not checked.

Comment: Did you try out my answer? Is it working now?

Comment: With your answer I have : Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.0.0.0
Listening on port 1495
Only local connections are allowed. And nothing is happening. Internet Explorer is not open and the test isn't performed.

Comment: See the Answer I have provided seperately & let me know still any issues. That is a proven code in IE which I have provided as an Answer.

Comment: Generally issues like this indicate mismatched browser/driver versions and are solved by updating the browser and Selenium drivers to the newest version.

Comment: I updated selenium version and IE (driver) to the newest but it didn't solve my problem. On : http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/, they said : Please make sure that this is available on your $PATH (or %PATH% on Windows) in order for the IE Driver to work as expected. I don't understand what I need to see in PATH ? Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give complete path to **IEDriverServer.exe**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

and the console ouput you have mentioned is absolutely fine , that is not an error. If you have noticed you will see the similar thing in both **Chrome** and **firefox**

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.3.0.0
Listening on port 17384
Only local connections are allowed
Mar 29, 2017 7:33:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Your actual problem is , in case of Intenet Explorer, Selenium is not able to locate REGISTER Webelement, which is working fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode". Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

My guess is that your issue is with Protected Mode.

Comment: Give the complete path didn't solved my problem. I am doing it on Internet Explorer because I can't install another one on my client's computer. Yes, that's a bit annoying I know !

Comment: So what can I do ? Because Internet Explorer finds the web adress but didn't do my instructions after it.

Comment: Updated my solution.

Comment: I think you are right. But this is a client computer. So I am not able to change that checkboxes. So I can't solve my problem with that

Comment: I tried with all the options, only by changing Internet explorer settings script is running fine

If you think i provided the right solution , then please accept the solution.

Comment: This is not the solution because it can't work for me. I can't change the checkbox.

Comment: Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Changing settings is the only solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question-

Replace your code by this:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability("platform", "WIN8"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("version", "11"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
    capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",1);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.navigate().to("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");
    driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

    driver.quit();
```

The last effort would be : Look in your registry under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
Settings\Zones key. Under there, you should see keys number 0-5. Under keys 1-4, look for a value named 2500, and list either the value for each of the keys, or if the value does not exist.

Having said that I would like you to go through [this link](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1795) where the issue is clearly discussed within Selenium User Group.

Also you may like you to go through [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/TdYzD5e9IxI) where the issue is being discussed within Selenium Developers Group.

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: What did you change ?

Comment: Is it working now? Let us first solve the issue then I will explain.

Comment: It is not working. I have the same issue. Internet Explorer is open but nothing is done on it. The output Junit is : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == REGISTER (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @Celia Great, we have overcome the initial IE issue. Can provide the element id/name/xpath instead of linktext ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @Celia Which version of IE are you using? In my set up (without Junit & Maven) its executing perfectly. I am using IE 10. Upgrade your IE if needed.Thanks

Comment: I am using IE11... I need to keep Junit and Maven for the next step of my project

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Celia I am looking out for a solution for you

Comment: Can you add these capabilities for IE 11 (change the object name as per se): `DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); caps.setCapability("platform", "WIN8"); caps.setCapability("version", "11"); caps.setCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");`

Comment: @Celia Did you try out the options I suggested in my comments with respect to IE 11? That should solve your problem.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dev, It didn't solve my problem but I haven't the same error : `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: @Celia So now we have come to the root cause of the error which is clearly conveyed to us. Now, I think to get over this issue you may need to consult the client site IT team. So if this Answer caters to your question can you accept the solution as the Answer & close the discussion thread?

Comment: I called the Service Desk but it is fixed by the client. And he doesn't want to change it. There isn't a solution ?